# Flink SQL SET statements not working in CLI

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am using Flink SQL client(Flink version 1.13.1) to submit my job, however, SET statements as mentioned in the doc(https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/sql/overview/) is giving me Parse Error, tried with *-i* file option as well.

command: ./bin/sql-client.sh embedded  -f /tmp/test.sql

Error:

```
    Flink SQL> -- DEBUGGING
SET 'sql-client.verbose' = 'true';
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.ParseException: Encountered "\'sql-client.verbose\'" at line 2, column 5.
Was expecting one of:
    <BRACKET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BACK_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <HYPHENATED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <UNICODE_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...


Shutting down the session...
done.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're copying multi lines in the SQL Client, so copying in the following:

```
--DEBUGGING
SET 'sql-client.verbose' = 'true';
```

This is currently not supported by the SQL client. If you remove the comment line, you will see that it the setting is properly executed:

```
Flink SQL> SET 'sql-client.verbose' = 'true';
[INFO] Session property has been set.
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure in 1.13.1 you need to remove the quotes around the property and value. The new quoted syntax was only introduced in 1.13.2 IIRC